Words that mean hidden, disguise, etc?
Specifically, I am looking for Latin words that mean hidden, disguise or illusion. I could use Google Translate to find these, but I would rather not, as my purpose for these words is going to be shown to (hopefully) hundreds of people.
Anyone know any Latin words that mean hidden, disguise or illusion?

You could look up each of the 3 words on Wiktionary. Latin.SE prefers questions that require more research to answer. Any more than 3 words outside a sentence and this would need more focus

@DanielT Now that you have enough reputation, I recommend voting to close and reopen questions as appropriate. It really makes a difference.

The word occultus is an adjective that means "hidden".
There is no regular classical Latin word for a disguise, but you can create one by adding the ending -tura to the supine of the verb simulo which means to counterfeit or disguise, viz simulatura. Other suffix-generated options would be simulatio and simulaticum (medieval Latin)  Another word construction that could be considered is latebrum. The word latebra is feminine and means a subterfuge or deception and is sometimes figuratively used to suggest a physical disguise, but by using the neuter form of this word, latebrum, it would directly imply a physical disguise. Just be aware that this is unattested in classical Latin.
The nouns vanum or simulatio or falsum or imago or error can mean an illusion.
